# How to match a simple equation term?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to make a regex that validates a simple equation term, complete with sign and power, including decimals, like any of the following:

> 2, 2.5, -2.5, -2.5^3, -2.5^3.7, +2, +2.5, …

But not:

> 2.
>
> -
>
> 2.5^

My best try was:

```
([-]|[+])?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)(\^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+?)?
```

But it would test as valid input like:

> 2.5.6
>
> 5^
>
> 6^^

How can I do this?

Comment: `2.` is a valid number as is `.2`

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you want to match? Your examples for example don't touch on `*` or `/` or `()`...

Comment: I want to match any valid term within a simple n power equation, excluding any *, / or (), just simple additions. A Full valid example would be `-2.5^3.7` or `+2.5^3.7` (excuse my lack of technical terminology as English is not my native language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex has two problems:

- It requires a dot `.` to be present, even if there are no digits following it, and
- It allows partial matches on the prefix or suffix, because it lacks *anchors*

Here is how you can fix both these problems:

```
^([-]|[+])?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)(\^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)?$
```

Adding `^` and `$` make sure that the whole string gets considered. Making `(\.[0-9]+)?` optional makes sure that a dot `.` can be omitted.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/iU2nA6/1)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is like this

`^[+-](?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:\^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))?$`

Formatted:

```
 ^ 
 [+-] 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  \. \d+ 
 )
 (?:
      \^
      (?:
           \d+ 
           (?: \. \d* )?
        |  \. \d+ 
      )
 )?
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

The regexp you used to match actually matches all the strings, as they contain a valid pattern.  If you want the whole string be matched only, you have to anchor your regexp to the sides, using `^` to anchor it to the beginning of line (or text) and `$` to anchor it to the end.  By the way, if you use something like `[0.9]+?`  you will be chaining a *one or more* operator with a *zero or one* making it effectively a `*` operator.

I you want the decimal part to be optional, you'll have to make groups, as in:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?(\^[+-]?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]*)?)?$
```

It's generally a good thing to think on subpatterns (as you have to repeat them verbatim) for numbers, like:

```
[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP7yO0/2)

## Note

I used `gm` modifiers in demo to allow for multiple matches and allow you to see them all in the same string.  As you want to match only one string and reject it if doesn't match, you don't need any of these modifiers.

Try modifying it to see changes, also.